# Having issues with Azure B2C

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms

I am using Azure Active Directory B2C in an application(Xamarin.forms). When i try to call the azure login page (which is a sign-in-policy), i am prompted with the following error:

"We track these errors automatically, but if the problem persists feel free to contact us. In the meantime, please try again.
Correlation ID: xxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx
Timestamp: 2021-01-28 17:08:40Z
AADB2C90011: The client id 'xxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx' provided in the request does not match client id 'xxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx' registered in policy"

i dont know what is going on, application id seems correct.

How do i fix it?

Comment: "if the problem persists feel free to contact us" - did you contact them?

Comment: I need to pay 30$ to contact them, or they suggest me come in here and ask, so here i am

Answer (score 0):

The client ID may be missing or incorrect in the **Web.config** file for the app.

You could have a try with follow these steps:

1. Open the Web.config file for the app.
2. In the Web.config file, find the app key **ida:ClientId**.
3. Replace the value of the app key with the client ID that is provided for your app in the Azure AD B2C admin portal.

The changed part of the file resembles the following:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="ida:ClientId" value="**xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx**">
</appSettings>
```